# How can I add the hero section image in the View to REST_API?

Tags: views, nodes, media, 9, paragraphs

- Hello im using Drupal 9.5.9 version. How can I add the hero section image in the View to REST_API?
- I have created an api with Rest_API to fetch data from Views I have created. I have no problem retrieving public data. However, I am getting "null"/"empty"/"id" errors when trying to get the image in the Hero Section in the View. I created two paths to get the images in the view, one to get all the views in the same category (jsonapi/news/) and the other to list the view whose id I entered (jsonapi/news/2775).
- After adding `Hero section` from the `Fields` section in the View to get the image, I tried to get the `img` tags by making `Rewrite results > Strip HTML tags` to get the image link properly, but I'm still having problems.
- - When I list all views in the same category (jsonapi/news) [image]
- - When I list a single view (jsonapi/news/id)[image]
- - When I list a single view (jsonapi/news/id) with strip img tags[image]
- - Another method I tried is Rewrite `Results > Override the output of this field with custom text` `{% if field_hero_section %} <img src="{{ file_url(field_hero_section.entity.field_image.entity) }}" /> {% endif % }`   I filtered by trying this code, but the result I got is; [image]

***How can i solve this ? Which method i should use ?***